# Add a future date manually to a Pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

Need to add a pyspark column with future_date: '9999-12-31' to a pyspark column

Tried:

```
.withColumn('valid_to_date', F.to_date(F.lit('9999-12-31'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

> Error:
>
> AssertionError: col should be Column

Comment: The code looks fine to run. what is your spark version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Perfectly fine , in my case , Can you share the entire stacktrace

```
d = {
        'date_col':['10-Oct-15', '11-Oct-17', '2-Feb-20', '02-Feb-20']
    }

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('valid_to_date', F.to_date(F.lit('9999-12-31'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))


sparkDF.show()

+---------+-------------+
| date_col|valid_to_date|
+---------+-------------+
|10-Oct-15|   9999-12-31|
|11-Oct-17|   9999-12-31|
| 2-Feb-20|   9999-12-31|
|02-Feb-20|   9999-12-31|
+---------+-------------+
```